# Android Vertical Shimmer

Tags: android, material-design, progress, shimmer

While navigating through [Android Material Components](https://material.io/design/motion/understanding-motion.html#principles), I came across this list loading animation.

[image]

I know a few libraries (e.g.[ShimmerLayout](https://github.com/team-supercharge/ShimmerLayout), Facebook's [Shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android)) which have horizontal loading animation. But it is not as smooth since it just renders the UI in a flash once you get the data.
If you look at the animation in the video, it actually displays vertical shimmer and renders response one by one.
I was wondering how can we achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can set top to bottom shimming direction using facebook [shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android)

```
    val container:ShimmerFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container)  

    val builder = Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder()
    builder.setDirection(com.facebook.shimmer.Shimmer.Direction.TOP_TO_BOTTOM)
    container.setShimmer(builder.build())
```

did not test it but it should work

Comment: You should also set builder.setTilt(0f) to remove the default angle of 20 degrees.